# Java 8 - Why does JFrame move?

Tags: java, swing, java-8

I recently updated to JDK and I've come across a very strange problem. I have a `JFrame` that I call the method `setLocationRelativeTo(parentJFrame)` and for some reason the `JFrame` flashes to the correct position before jumping to the top left of my screen and slowly slides down until it hits the bottom of the screen. Why does it do this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you add images? Code snippets? More information? Your problem also sounds hilarious out of context :)

Comment: Did you call setVisible before or after

Comment: I called `setVisible` before. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Wow, that fixed it, thank you! Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you call `setVisible` last, after you've initialised the UI and defined its size and position, preferably using `pack` and `setLocationRelativeTo`